# Ag-grid Excel export - Aggregate rows in exported excel

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid with column definitions with aggregate rows as below.
I want to enable the export to excel option to also export the aggregate row.

**What params should I configure to enable export of the aggregate rows from the grid?**

```
this.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel(params) //<-------What param config to use

//Ag-Grid column Definitions
columnDefs: [
        {
          field: "athlete",
          filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
          minWidth: 200
        },
        { field: "age",aggFunc:"sum" }, //<-------Aggregate columns
        {
          field: "country",
          minWidth: 180
        },
        { field: "year" },
        {
          field: "date",
          minWidth: 150
        },
        { field: "gold", aggFunc:"sum" },//<-------Aggregate columns
        { field: "silver", aggFunc:"sum" },//<-------Aggregate columns
        { field: "bronze", aggFunc:"sum" },//<-------Aggregate columns
        { field: "total", aggFunc:"sum" }//<-------Aggregate columns
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Group rows, including the aggregated values, are exported by default.
Here an example where I export the aggregations and additionally I highlight them by adding a background colour.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Kp3bbQREecmwDLxf

Relevant for that are:

```
{ field: 'gold', aggFunc: 'sum',
  cellClassRules: {
    'aggregatedValue': params => params.node.group
  } 
},
```

and

```
excelStyles: [
    {
      id: "aggregatedValue",
      interior: {
        color: "#e8f7ba", pattern: 'Solid'
      },
      font: { bold:true}
    }
  ],
```

Also, if you want to customise the headers/cells for aggregations, you may find useful these callbacks:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/excel-export-api/#reference-ExcelExportParams-processGroupHeaderCallback
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/excel-export-api/#reference-ExcelExportParams-processRowGroupCallback